# Html image-content layout

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get the image and content side by side in the layout. Something like the way they have done it [here](https://www.wishberry.in/about/). I have tried the bootstrap grid layout for doing it but I am just not getting it right plus it is not responsive.Can someone please help me out with this.

Here is the skeleton of the code:

`<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <img src=""/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <div><h4></h4></div>
                            <p class="text-muted"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <img src=""/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <div><h4></h4></div>
                            <p class="text-muted"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
 </div>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  //image here 
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
 //text here 
</div>
```

Hope this helps!